# Trying to sort and display data from a single mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've looked for about an hour. I may even be looking for the wrong thing, because I'm sure this is a common practice. In the past, I would have just ran mutliple querys or had something hard coded, but I'm trying to do things the most efficient way.

I have a query that brings back this data:

```
factoryId | serviceID | serviceName
    1         1001        repair
    1         1002        recycle
    1         1003        transfer
    2         1001        repair
    2         1002        recycle
    2         1003        transfer
    3         1001        repair
    3         1002        recycle
    3         1003        transfer
```

I need to put it into sections with headers... 
// switch statement determines factory name from id ?>
**Factory One**

- Repair
- Recycle
- Transfer

**Factory Two**

- Repair
- Recycle
- Transfer

**Factory Three**

- Repair
- Recycle
- Transfer

I think the solution is with multi-dimensional arrays, but not sure how to write the array, and then (2 foreach loops?) to echo the formatted result.

Comment: yes you can have an array as $array= array("Factory One"=>array("Repair","Recycle","Transfer"),...);

Comment: just query the data, and use recursive function to build an array as abhik exemplified EDIT: simple for cycle is enough

Comment: This is a simple (while) loop.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I needed the code structure as presented by @abhik-chakraborty. I appreciate you taking time to help though. Strawberry, you may have misunderstood my question, but thanks still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this is what you can do, I am not using the query but generated an array which is similar to mysql_fetch_assoc();

```
<?php
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory One","serviceName"=>"repair");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory One","serviceName"=>"recycle");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory One","serviceName"=>"transfer");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory Two","serviceName"=>"repair");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory Two","serviceName"=>"recycle");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory Two","serviceName"=>"transfer");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory three","serviceName"=>"repair");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory three","serviceName"=>"recycle");
$array[] = array("factory"=>"Factory three","serviceName"=>"transfer");

$group_array = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    $group_array[$val["factory"]][] = $val["serviceName"];
}

foreach($group_array as $key=>$val){
    echo '<b>'.$key.'</b><br />';
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        echo '-'.$v.'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

The first loop is similar to looping the query result and creating a group array and then finally loop the group array to display the data.

Comment: This worked! I had to just adjust a few things and troubleshoot. (Originally I ran this inside the while($factory=$query->fetch(){..}.) Then I tried just the $array[] part inside and the rest outside of the mysql->fetch()). I also simplified the $array[] = array(...); to $array[] = $factory; (the array returned from the query).   Thanks so much for your answer. I knew I was on the right track with the multiple foreach() loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Make sure to write your query appending ASC or DESC to *factoryID*

```
<?php

//Place a counter for factoryId

$countid_fid = 1;
$reset = 0; //this decides if the title should be printed or not. 1 means dont print.
//loop 

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {

    $fid = $row->factoryID;

    if($countid_fid == $fid) {
        if($reset = 0) {            
            echo $row->serviceName; //title
            $reset = 1;
        }       
    }else{
        $reset = 0; 
    }
    //rest of your code to show data



}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
SELECT * FROM factory GROUP BY factoryId;
```